# wso2 esb http status message

Tags: http, wso2-esb

Is there any way to get http status message in synapse config? I have got status code using next code `<property name="status" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"/>` but no luck with status message. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported in any of the WSO2 ESB versions yet. If you have control over your backend service, you can return those HTTP status messages in a custom HTTP header - then you should be able to read this custom HTTP header as below.

```
<property name="HTTP_SM" expression="get-property('axis2','CUSTOM_HEADER')"/>
```

Comment: Hi Depository, thanks for your response. My WSO2 version is 4.0.3, the quite old one). Your solution is to send needed for me data in custom header and catch it in synapse config, but it is third party system and it sends us custom status message with default status code.

Answer (score 0):

Our company has sent official request to wso2 support with this question and his answer is that it's impossible for our version (4.0.3). 
Our decision is to try get this data using custom mediator.

Comment: It is not possible to get it using custom class mediator too. This particular HTTP status message is not there in any of the Transport Headers. There is only one workaround to this issue which is to send this HTTP status message in a custom header from your backend, then it will be available as a transport header inside ESB.

Comment: it's not our backend, and it is the problem. we call separate legacy system and this system responses with custom values in status property. that is why we need to have this header property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get http status message:

```
<property name="message" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC_DESC"/>
```